# HTML5 section headers

Tags: html

I have gotten myself rather confused. In HTML5 its best to include headings for each section for screen readers and alike, then hide the ones you don't want to display. My question is, what heading number is best to use. Do you use the flow as you normally would, or can you just use anything like always h6, or h1 etc? The reason I ask, is if you are hiding them, surely you could end up missing out heading tags in the flow.

Answer (score 0):

The outline algorithm changed for HTML5, it makes it possible to have a whole stack of "h1-h6" per sectioning element. For more information, read that excellent article on HTML5 Doctor: http://html5doctor.com/outlines/